# SQL ID error- Insert and Update not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure for inserting and updating values in a table. The issue is that when I update the form it I get this error

> Procedure or function 'sp_AddUpdatePages' expects parameter '@Id', which was not supplied.

My `Id` column is set to `Identity` in the SQL Server table. Also please see my stored procedure for your reference:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Sp_addupdatepages 
(@Id INT, 
 @page_title NVARCHAR(100), 
 @page_description NVARCHAR(max), 
 @meta_title       NVARCHAR(255), 
 @meta_keywords    NVARCHAR(255), 
 @meta_description NVARCHAR(1000), 
 @Active BIT) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET nocount ON; 

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM   tbl_pages 
              WHERE  id = @Id) 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE [tbl_pages] 
        SET    [page_title] = @page_title, 
               [page_description] = @page_description, 
               [meta_title] = @meta_title, 
               [meta_keywords] = @meta_keywords, 
               [meta_description] = @meta_description, 
               [active] = @Active 
        WHERE  id = @Id 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO [tbl_pages] 
                    ([page_title], 
                     [page_description], 
                     [meta_title], 
                     [meta_keywords], 
                     [meta_description], 
                     [active]) 
        VALUES      (@page_title, 
                     @page_description, 
                     @meta_title, 
                     @meta_keywords, 
                     @meta_description, 
                     @Active) 
    END 

    SELECT [page_title], 
         [page_description], 
         [meta_title], 
         [meta_keywords], 
         [meta_description], 
         [active] 
    FROM tbl_pages 
END
```

This is my code behind:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_AddUpdatePages";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page_title", txtPageTitle.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page_description", txtPagedesc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta_title", txtmetatitle.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta_keywords", txtMetakeywords.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta_description", txtMetadesc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", ddlActiveInactive.SelectedIndex);

            grdCSRPageData.DataSource = this.GetData(cmd);
            grdCSRPageData.DataBind();

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Page Added succesfully')</script>");
        }
    }
```

SQL Server table `tbl_Pages`:

```
Id int unchecked 
page_title nvarchar(100) unchecked 
page_description nvarchar(max) unchecked 
meta_title nvarchar(255) unchecked 
meta_keywords nvarchar(255) unchecked 
meta_description nvarchar(1000) unchecked 
active bit checked unchecked
```

Comment: Please show the table definition of tbl_pages.

Comment: Please check the code, Your sp takes @Id as input but you are not passing the Id value in the code behind.(on Add button click.)

Comment: @PareshJ: See the edited question for the table definition

Comment: I dont see your column ID has been set to IDENTITY.

Comment: @PareshJ: yes it is identity set and working fine

Comment: Assuming you have ID column set as Identity, then check your code. You need to pass another cmd.parameter for ID column as your stored procedure takes '@ID' as input parameter. Your Stored proc is taking 7 parameters and from code behind you are passing 6 parameters. Check and correct it.

Comment: @PareshJ: but my Id is set to identity when creating the new Row. So how to add that, Or can you tell me how to make change in the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Nadeem, you have to change the code and add ID parameter. In case of Update, you will need the ID parameter to be passed from code behind.

Comment: @PareshJ: can you help me with that part of code ? please

Comment: In case of Update, are you capturing ID value somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you can see the Stored procedure.

Comment: In the code behind are you capturing the ID value somewhere not in sp? So that it will help you to identity which row you are gonna update.

Comment: For now, I am not capturing the ID from code behind.

Comment: Nadeem, when you are updating record, you must be retrieving it from database for updation. Select and save ID value in that case on page either in hiddenfield or session, etc and pass this value at the time of calling ADDUPDATE stored proc. Check this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/insert-update-delete-in-gridview-using-single-stored-proce/

Comment: @PareshJ: So In my case, I am taking hiddenfield as mentioned in the link and pass it at the time of ADD/UPDATE

Comment: Yes, you can use hidden field. It will be balnk in case of ADD and while UPDATE, it will contains ID value of the row that is getting updated(You must capture ID value of row that is getting updated to set hidden field value)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65515/discussion-between-nadeem-khan-and-paresh-j).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s: can you help me with this

Comment: As the error message already clearly says, and as others have already pointed out, it's pretty clear: you have an `@Id` parameter in your list of stored procedure parameters, but you're never supplying a value for it from your C# code .....

Comment: @marc_s: The Id column is set to Identity and I am passing it as NULL, and calling as hidden field value from code behind, still it is not working

Comment: Your `SqlCommand` **does not** have a parameter `@Id` - and yes, it's an identity which gets set automatically for `INSERT` - but you **also** cover `UPDATE` with the same procedure (bad idea to begin with - **one** procedure should always do **ONE THING ONLY** - not several things!) and for the `UPDATE`, you **must supply** the value for `@Id` !

Comment: Ok, I will handle this Stored procedure for Inserting, how to start with the UPDATE one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont have an ID to sent to the procedure.
you should set default value to @ID parameter in the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Sp_addupdatepages (@Id               INT=NULL, 
                               @page_title       NVARCHAR(100), 
                               @page_description NVARCHAR(max), 
                               @meta_title       NVARCHAR(255), 
                               @meta_keywords    NVARCHAR(255), 
                               @meta_description NVARCHAR(1000), 
                               @Active           BIT)
```

and then it wont through exception

Comment: but will it get increment in the table when the new Row has been added ?

Comment: I added that NULL in the SP, but it is giving me error now as "Procedure or function 'sp_AddUpdatePages' expects parameter '@page_title', which was not supplied."

Comment: in the insert statement you shouldn't insert the id if it's not supplied, as you did. about the second comment: beside the change of the value 'Null' is there other changes?

Comment: No there is nothing I changed besides adding the ID=NULL, See my code-behind from the question, you will get an idea